# What does this statement mean in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

What does this statement mean?

```
im3 = appendimages(im1,zeros(size(im1,1),gap));
```

`appendimages` is the function for concatenation and `gap=100`, but what does this whole statement do?

Comment: Looks like it's not a standard MATLAB function is it? At least I didn't find it in my MATLAB 2010b.. Look around for the source of this function.. Does 'help appendimages' yield anything??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like a standard function. But I think I can understand what it does from the description.

This line `zeros(size(im1,1),gap)` just creates an array of `0`s with the same number of rows as `im1` and as many columns as specified in `gap` (100 as you say). So possibly, the function `appendimages()` joins this zero matrix to either the left end or the right end of the image `im1`. Left or right depends on the actual definition of the function.

You can also join another image `im2` to `im1` as `appendimage(im1,im2)`.

Comment: yes appendimages is not a standard function ,its a user defind function which will concatenate images.