# how to concatenate an image with a matrix horizontally in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have an image `img`.  I want to conactenate it with a matrix of zeros, but horizontally
i-e image should appear with black color.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of one of your previous questions: [how to combine two images on one window matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037779/how-to-combine-two-images-on-one-window-matlab) The only difference is that one of your images is now a matrix of zeros (i.e. a black image).

Comment: @gnovice Good point. Maybe he hasnt checked it yet or doesnt know how to

Comment: @gnovice: yes, and also related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777881/what-does-this-statement-mean-in-matlab) that the OP asked this morning. He has a function that does the concatenation & he has a statement that concatenates with zeros. He posted a question asking what it meant, and an answer was given. I don't see why this question was asked. OP has a pattern of asking repeated questions that are just an epsilon different from the previous question, something that could've been addressed in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started, this adds a row of zeros to the bottom of a grayscale image:

```
result = [img; zeros(1,size(img,2))]
```

and this does the same to an rgb image:

```
result = [img; zeros(1,size(img,2),3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

To add zeros on to the right hand side of an image

newImg=cat(2,img,zeros(size(img,1),numNewColumns,size(img,3)));